# How to transform indented list to table?

Tags: javascript, parsing, data-structures

---

Hello, everyone!

Regardless of the task or the platform I've realized that I'm doing roughly the same thing over and over again. Transform list to indented list, filling the gaps, consolidating the data, converting to edible json.

When using excel it's tedious but straightforward. How do I do the same task using javascript (or Node.js parser)? [image: Data flow]

It'd be greatly appreciated if someone could provide a live example of how to perform this task. Do I use GREP to connect to data levels?

The sample data (matches the picture):

```
<h1 class="level1">Header content aa</h1>
<h1 class="level1">Header content ab</h1>
    <h1 class="level2">Header content ac</h1>
        <p>Content block a</p>
    <h1 class="level2">Header content ad</h1>
        <p>Content block b</p>
        <p>Content block c</p>
<h1 class="level1">Header content ae</h1>
        <p>Content block d</p>      
    <h1 class="level2">Header content af</h1>
        <p>Content block e</p>
<h1 class="level1">Header content ag</h1>
        <p>Content block f</p>
        <p>Content block g</p>
```

The desired result is something like:

```
[
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ab",
   "Sublevel": "Header content ac",
   "Content": "Content block a"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ab",
   "Sublevel": "Header content ad",
   "Content": "Content block b"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ab",
   "Sublevel": "Header content ad",
   "Content": "Content block c"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ae",
   "Sublevel": null,
   "Content": "Content block d"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ae",
   "Sublevel": "Header content af",
   "Content": "Content block e"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ag",
   "Sublevel": null,
   "Content": "Content block f"
 },
 {
   "Topmost level": "Header content ag",
   "Sublevel": null,
   "Content": "Content block g"
 }
]
```

I really want to get a grip on best practices of how to perform such a task by using JS. And the sample code would be the best help to achieve that.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How do you have this data as HTML or file? give a little bit more clear about your source

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.
This time I've parsed RSS - that's where the example comes from. But I clearly remember that I had to do the subj. when reorganizing messy internal excel table, and when I've been preparing json for d3.js with data about cities.

So the origin of data isn't that important as I dare to think.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure requires reading each header subheader and content creating something like line per line array then reducing it by using most recent header state to add content to array:

```
let h1, h2, h3; // for keeping track of last header state
[...document.querySelectorAll('body > *')].map((el) => [[...el.classList].join(' '), el.innerText]).reduce((result, [level, content]) => {
  switch (level) {
    case 'level1':
      h1 = content;
      h2 = null;
      h3 = null;
      break;
    case 'level2':
      h2 = content;
      h3 = null;
      break;
    default:
      h3 = content;
  }

  if (h1 && h3) {
    result.push({ "Topmost level": h1, "Sublevel": h2, "Content": h3 })
  }
  return result;
}, [])
```